# formData is not empty but sails.js gets empty req.body with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, sails.js, form-data

I am using vue.js and sails.js together, I need to create a product with a picture and other text values, I created a formData object out of the whole form and append some data to it. When I tend to log out the data it is not empty but when I use the `req.body` or `req.params` it shows empty object.
My code is below:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  formData.append('owner', cid);
  formData.append('name', this.name);
  formData.append('slug', this.slug);
  formData.append('description', this.editorData);
  formData.append('tags', this.tags);
  formData.append('categories', this.categories);
  formData.append('stock', this.stock);
  formData.append('price', this.price);

  for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
    console.log(key, value);
  }


  axios.post(API + 'product/new', formData)
  .then(function(response) {
    swal("ok",{
      icon: "success",
      button: false,
    });   
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    swal("not ok",{
      icon: "error",
      button: false,
    }); 
    console.log(error.response);
      // remain silent
  });
```

Comment: If you are uploading a file, I reckon you will need to encode the form with the content type multipart/form-data. So your axios post would need to be something like `axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: API + 'product/new',
    data: formData,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    }).then(...`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue now as i have been at it for 3 days now.
The solution is simple, SailsJs req.body object would only read your formdata object or what ever object you pass to it as long as it does not come after a file object, that's if you have any.

For better understanding check out their documentation on req.body [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-body)

Comment: That doc says this: "If a request contains one or more file uploads, only the text parameters sent ***before*** the first file parameter will be available in `req.body`." Does this mean that, client-side, the HTML **should** have the file-type `input` elements last? (Or, with client-side JS as in your case, `formData` should be built such that file objects are appended last?)